# Control power to load by turning on/off regulator or by using a transistor

Tags: switching-regulator

I am working on a project that involves a load that draws a little over 16A at 3.6VDC and it needs to turn on and off at 10Hz ~ 15Hz for 5~10 seconds at a time. I plan on using an arduino to control the circuit.

I have decided on a regulator to provide the steady voltage that can handle 20A, a TPS53353.

My question is, would it work to turn the regulator on and off using the arduino to provide the intermittent power to the load or would it be better to leave the regulator on and use a separate transistor to turn the load on and off using the arduino.

Comment: Stupid question, but you're not powering that regulator from the Arduino, are you?

Comment: haha, not a stupid question at all. Its getting power from a separate power source(6 ~12V battery). Sorry I should have included that.

Comment: All things being equal, unless there's a reason not to, I'd switch after the buck converter just to avoid all the research into whether it's OK to just switch the converter.

Comment: That would be the easiest way, I am just trying to keep the component count low so I thought I would ask. I guess I'm off to find a suitable FET.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: What's the load? Is it inductive or capacitive? Does it have any ability to deliver energy back to the supply when the supply is shut off?

Comment: Cree XM-L2 LEDs

Comment: Uh-oh. You're not planning to apply 3.6 directly to the LEDs, are you?

Comment: Well, its going to be more like 3.3~3.4 volts, should I not be applying it directly?

Comment: Changing from zero to 100 percent load on the output of a switching regulator may not be the best idea to keep down transients and out of regulation behavior. I would definately consider using the enable pin on the regulator. That is the reason the controllers come with these pins.

Answer (score 1):

If the regulator can turn on and off fast enough for you (the datasheet has plenty of info on how long it needs to turn on - I think it will but I didn't do the math), I believe you can control the enable pin directly from the arduino. That makes it easier to control and the regulator doesnt have to deal with the full power loss every time.